# How to download a file in Office.js excel add-in on mac using Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow API?

Tags: javascript, excel, office365, office-js, office-addins

I want to download a base64-encoded file from my Excel add-in. The following code successfully downloads the file when I try it from a browser:

```
function run() {
    const sampleBase64Data = 'VGVzdCBhdHRhY2htZW50';
    const binaryData = atob(sampleBase64Data);
    const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(binaryData.length);
    const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (let i = 0; i < binaryData.length; i++) {
        uint8Array[i] = binaryData.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const blob = new Blob([uint8Array], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });

    const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    downloadLink.download = 'sampleFile.txt';
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    downloadLink.click();
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

However, this approach doesn't work with the macOS version of Excel and installed Excel on Windows. The workaround is to use Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow(url);. This API doesn't work if I supply the object URL of the file in the above sample. How can I download a file from its base64-encoded string using Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow(url);?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to follow this [Office Add-in JavaScript FileDownload not working with MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77940501/how-to-download-a-file-in-office-js-excel-add-in-on-mac-using-office-context-ui)

but my personal experience is on it first save the file in any project folder and then get its url and use it like this :

```
  window.open(fileUrl, '_blank');
```

this was working fine for me.